# How to remove images from folder which are not listed in CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, directory, notin

I'm trying to remove all the images which are not listed in the CSV file. Data comes to CSV in the format described below.

Problem is that script is going to delete every file in the images folder. I only want to delete images that do not contain SKU (example "7-5468-XXX7") from the CSV file. What to do here?

Trying to use this:

```
$filestokeep = Import-Csv "C:\Users\example\filestokeep.csv"
    $files = Get-ChildItem  "C:\Users\example\images\"

    $files |
        Where-Object Name -notin $filestokeep.sku |
        Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

filestokeep.csv looks like:

```
"sku"
"1-123-X"
"2-123-XXXXX"
"3-562-XXXX"
"4-215-XXXXXX"
"5-56482-XX-X"
"6-45688"
"7-5468-XXX"
"856-54648-X"
```

C:\Users\example\images\ containing files such as:

```
1-123-X.jpg
2-123-XXXXX.jpg
1-123-X_1.jpg
1-123-X_2.jpg
7-5468-XXX7.jpg
7-5468-XXX7_1.jpg
7-5468-XXX7_2.jpg
6-45688.jpg
```

Images folder should look like this after running:

```
1-123-X.jpg
2-123-XXXXX.jpg
1-123-X_1.jpg
1-123-X_2.jpg
6-45688.jpg
```

Link to original code that I am trying to implement:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8f2z0l/remove_files_not_in_csv/

Comment: `Where-Object Name -notin $filestokeep.sku` --> `Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notin $filestokeep.sku }`. Also, for safety add switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet so you're not processing subfolders. Anyway, your desired output does not match the description because it also shows files that are **IN** the csv..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adding `-File` sure do makes everything more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FilesToKeep.csv` file contains lists of FileNames like `1-123-X`.

You're comparing this to the `Name` property which includes the `FileExtension`, so you're comparing your list of just file names against something like `\1-123-X_1.jpg` which includes the extension.

To be clear the comparison looks like this:

```
Name             Sku
1-123-X_1.jpg    1-123-X_1  #doesn't match because Windows cares about the .jpg piece
```

See why this isn't working?  The extension is in one group and not the other!

The fix is very easy, just compare against the `BaseName` property instead, like this:

```
 $files |
        Where-Object BaseName -notin $filestokeep.sku |
        Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

That will result in this comparison happening instead:

```
BaseName     Sku
1-123-X_1    1-123-X_1  #MATCHES!
```

And when you then go ahead and run the full script, you'll see an output of this, showing what would happen if you removed `-WhatIf`.

```
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\temp\Files\1-123-X_1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\temp\Files\1-123-X_2.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\temp\Files\7-5468-XXX7.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\temp\Files\7-5468-XXX7_1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\temp\Files\7-5468-XXX7_2.jpg".
```

Comment: Basename helped a lot, but I also want keep images which include the sku. For examaple if sku is "1-123-X" files with names like "1-123-X_1.jpg" and "1-123-X_2.jpg" should not be deleted. Can you somehow add wildcards around the sku?

Thank you for great info so far.

Comment: Ask that as a new question, it's possible but would required a rewrite of your logic entirely and doesn't fit this question.

Comment: New question right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445840/how-to-delete-all-the-files-from-folder-where-name-does-not-include-string-liste

Comment: Remember to vote up, and accept as answer if this was helpful to getting the problem solved :)